# How to create a native X11 window for use with EGL

Tags: c, opengl, x11, egl

How does one create a native X11 window that works in EGL? Going through the [`eglIntro`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/EGL/sdk/docs/man/html/eglIntro.xhtml) there is little documentation on the matter. Alternatively, is there a way to create native windows through EGL itself? There is an `EGLNativeWindowType` that I assume can be used instead of whatever X11's native window types are.

Answer (score 3):

No, EGL itself does not provide an Xlib wrapper. You have to create the window by yourself.

Here is a minimal sample to get you started. It refers to GLES2, but it should work with GLES1 also.

First, you declare the Xlib objects(display and window).

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xatom.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>

#include  <GLES2/gl2.h>
#include  <EGL/egl.h>

// Native handles for window and display
Window      win;
Display* xdisplay;

// EGL-related objects
EGLDisplay  egl_display;
EGLConfig   egl_conf;
EGLContext  egl_context;
EGLSurface  egl_surface;

int init_egl()
{
    EGLint attr[] = {
        EGL_SURFACE_TYPE,    EGL_WINDOW_BIT,
        EGL_RED_SIZE,        8,
        EGL_GREEN_SIZE,      8,
        EGL_BLUE_SIZE,       8,
        // EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE, EGL_OPENGL_ES2_BIT, /* If one needs GLES2 */
        EGL_NONE
    };

    EGLint num_config;
    EGLint major, minor;

    EGLint ctxattr[] = {
       EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION, 2,
       EGL_NONE
    };

    egl_display  =  eglGetDisplay( (EGLNativeDisplayType) xdisplay );
    if ( egl_display == EGL_NO_DISPLAY ) {
        printf("Error getting EGL display\n");
        return 0;
    }

    if ( !eglInitialize( egl_display, &major, &minor ) ) {
        printf("Error initializing EGL\n");
        return 0;
    }

    printf("EGL major: %d, minor %d\n", major, minor);

    /* create EGL rendering context */
    if ( !eglChooseConfig( shell->egl_display, attr, &shell->egl_conf, 1, &num_config ) ) {
        printf("Failed to choose config (eglError: %x)\n", eglGetError());
        return 0;
    }

    if ( num_config != 1 ) {
        return 0;
    }

    egl_surface = eglCreateWindowSurface ( egl_display, egl_conf, win, NULL );
    if (egl_surface == EGL_NO_SURFACE ) {
        printf("CreateWindowSurface, EGL eglError: %d\n", eglGetError() );
        return 0;
    }

    egl_context = eglCreateContext ( egl_display, egl_conf, EGL_NO_CONTEXT, ctxattr );
    if ( egl_context == EGL_NO_CONTEXT ) {
        printf("CreateContext, EGL eglError: %d\n", eglGetError() );
        return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

From the `main` function you will call the X event handler procedure. I have left commented `printf` calls to show how the event values are named, so there's no need to lookup the documentation. If the concept of "Event loop" is not clear, then I recommend reading about general UI event processing.

```
void process_xevent(XEvent xev) {
    //    XNextEvent( xdisplay, &xev );
    switch (xev.type)
    {
        case MotionNotify:
            // printf("motion: %d %d\n", xev.xbutton.x, xev.xbutton.y);
            break;
        case KeyRelease:
            // printf("rel (%d)\n", XLookupKeysym (&xev.xkey, 0));
            break;
        case KeyPress:
            // printf("keypress (%d)\n", XLookupKeysym (&xev.xkey, 0));
            break;
        case ButtonPress:
            // printf("BPress: state = %d, button = %d, x = %d, y = %d\n", xev.xbutton.state, xev.xbutton.button, xev.xbutton.x, xev.xbutton.y);
            // printf("Type=%d\n", (int)xev.xbutton.type);
            break;
        case ButtonRelease:
            // printf("BRelease: state = %d, button = %d, x = %d, y = %d\n", xev.xbutton.state, xev.xbutton.button, xev.xbutton.x, xev.xbutton.y);
            // printf("Type=%d\n", (int)xev.xbutton.type);
            break;
    }
}
```

Finally, in the main() routine you create and open display/Xwindow.

```
int main()
{
    int egl_error;

    Window root;
    XSetWindowAttributes  swa;

    /* open standard display (primary screen) */
    xdisplay = XOpenDisplay ( NULL );   
    if ( xdisplay == NULL ) {
        printf("Error opening X display\n");
        return 0;
    }
```

The window is created and shown once you have the Display opened.

Finally, in the main() routine you create and open display/Xwindow.

```
    // get the root window (usually the whole screen)
    root  =  DefaultRootWindow( shell->xdisplay );

    // list all events this window accepts
    swa.event_mask =
    StructureNotifyMask |
    ExposureMask        |
    PointerMotionMask   |
    KeyPressMask        |
    KeyReleaseMask      |
    ButtonPressMask     |
    ButtonReleaseMask;

    // Xlib's window creation
    win  =  XCreateWindow (
        xdisplay, root, 0, 0, 640, 480,   0,
        CopyFromParent, InputOutput, CopyFromParent, CWEventMask,
       &swa );

    XMapWindow ( xdisplay , win );         // make window visible
    XStoreName ( xdisplay , win , "EGL" );
```

When you have the window, intialise the EGL.

```
    egl_error = init_egl();
    if (!egl_error) {
        return 1;
    }
```

Once you have the EGL & Xlib objects, you can start the event processing loop.

```
while (1) {
        int keycode;
        XEvent  xev;

        if ( XPending ( xdisplay ) )
            if (XCheckWindowEvent(shell->xdisplay, shell->win, global_event_mask, &xev))
                process_xevent(shell, xev);

       /* if (should_exit) { break; }   // set some global flag if you want to exit */

       eglMakeCurrent( egl_display, egl_surface, egl_surface, egl_context );

       /* Call OpenGL as you see fit */

       /* get rendered buffer to the screen */
       eglSwapBuffers ( egl_display, egl_surface );
   }


   // deinitialize
}
```

This should get you started. The code is extracted from a larger project, so there might have be typos introduced while removing irrelevant things.

To conclude the answer and to be more precise, here `EGLNativeWindowType` is specialized to `Window` from `X11/Xlib.h` header and `EGLNativeDisplayType` is `Display*`.

An easier way might be to use `libxcb`, but I do not have any tested sample code. The [GLFW library](https://github.com/glfw/glfw) can be a useful source of OS-dependant OpenGL context creation routines.

Comment: Thanks. With a little bit of tweaking this provides me a standard black window. With a little more tweaking I can integrate it with my project.

Comment: glClearColor + glClear combo provides a standard non-black window as a next test )